# Manipulate Cuboid for Rotation

Tags: manipulate, graphics3d, rotation

Using the example code from the cuboid:

```
Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[],Table[{ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[c, {0, 2 Pi}]],GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[],RotationTransform[c, {-1, 2, -3},{1.5, 0, 0}]]}, {c, 0, 2 Pi, 2 Pi/12}]}]
```

I'm trying to manipulate it so it shows one image after the other. I changed it in this way:

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.3],EdgeForm[], {ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[a, {0, 2 Pi}]],GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[],RotationTransform[a, {-1, 2, -3}, {1.5, 0, 0}]]}}], {a, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

But that doesn't keep the same scale, I wanted to show one cube at a time but in the way displayed in the first code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple trick that does what you want.  We can include a transparent sphere in our scene that is large enough that MMA does not zoom in on each successive the cuboid.  We can do that by adding `Opacity[0],Sphere[center,radius]` to our list of graphics directives, but what center and what radius should we use?

A check of the documentation for `RotationTransformation` shows that the rotation is about an axis through the anchor point `{1.5,0,0}`, so we can use that as our center.  How big should the sphere be?  Maybe a 1.5 radius, maybe a little bigger.  We don't want to make it too big.

A little experimentation gives the following code with a radius of 2, which seems to work well.

```
Manipulate[Graphics3D[{
   Opacity[0.03], Sphere[{1.5, 0, 0}, 2],
   Opacity[0.3], EdgeForm[], {
    ColorData["Rainbow"][Rescale[a, {0, 2 Pi}]],
    GeometricTransformation[Cuboid[],
     RotationTransform[a, {-1, 2, -3}, {1.5, 0, 0}]]
    }}],
 {a, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Your `Manipulate` works pretty good.  In the above, the sphere shows faintly, just so we can see it.  Change its opacity to zero for complete transparency.

Comment: What a simple solution! Worked perfectly, thank you!